# Should Angular client store user roles in local storage?

Tags: angular, .net-core, local-storage, roles

In my Angular app, based on the logged in user, I would like to grant or limit functionality by showing/hiding different menu items or allowing/disallowing certain routes. 
Currently on successful login, my .NET Core API returns a JWT Token along with the user's Role and stores it in local storage. I then use this to display my menu (for example). 
I'm just having doubts that this is the best practice as it exposes my user's role and I'm not sure what might happen if someone manually changes this in local storage.

[image]

Is there a better/more secure way of achieving this?

Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change your JWT token manually, because it was generated used private key (or secret key). Without private key you can't create new token with updated roles. So user is not able to do this. Of course he can decode token, but he can't encode valid new one

Comment: Right, I understand the JWT is secure. However in my local storage I have something like the following : (See image in original question) Is this OK?

Comment: No, you should keep in local storage only raw JWT token, decoded version should be stored in some kind of authentication service in your application. Because if you are using this decoded object, user can very easy replace every value. Summarizing, don't save decoded JWT to `LocalStorage`, decode JWT only in authentication service and keep this decoded object in private value so that the user cannot access

Comment: But this is only dangerous in case when you are checking this roles on front - like access to some routes, displaying admin buttons or something like that - because backend will know that this user with this JWT token doesn't has this roles